# so search path redefinition

Tags: gcc, path, linker, shared-libraries

ALL,

Is there an option I can pass to either configure or to the project to redefine the so library search path.

I am using Anjuta to do development. My project consists of the executable binaries and couple of projects which produces the dynamically linked library.
I was told by Anjuta maintainers that I will have to run "make install" in order to either run or debug the program, since by default the search path for an so is coming from "/usr/lib;/usr/local/lib".

However, I am still developing and I'd like to keep everything locally and don't install anything if I don't have to.

So if such an option exists, which can define my library search path to become "~/my_project/Debug/", as an addition to the standard ones either permanently or temporarily, it would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what platform you are using, but most UNIX variants allow you to do *exactly* what you want by setting

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/my_project/Debug
```

If you are using Linux or Solaris, you could add `-Wl,-rpath=$HOME/my_project/Debug` to the link step for the binary and shared libraries you are using (instead of setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

Comment: will this include $HOME/my_project/Debug/projN, where N is some number?

Comment: @Igor No. You should read the runtime loader man page, probably `man ld.so`.

Comment: is this the same as give the "-Wl,-rpath/home/igor/my_project/Debug" or this is different?